# Converting json date value to proper format (Y-m-d H:i:s)

Tags: php, json, date, post

how i can change this Date : Tue Oct 29 20:36:21 +1100 2013 to proper format (Y-m-d H:i:s) in php?

Comment: You should add a PHP-tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$time = "Tue Oct 29 20:36:21 +1100 2013";
echo date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time));
```

This will print time in your current time zone.